# MPI fortran code on top of another one

Tags: fortran, mpi

I wrote a MPI fortran program that I need to run multiple times (for consistency let call this program P1). The **minimum** number of core that I can use to run a program is 512. The problem is that P1 has the best scalability with 128 cores.
What I want to do is to create another program (P2) on top of P1, that call P1 4 times simultaneously, each of the call would be on 128 cores..

Basically I need to run 4 instances of a call simultaneously with a number of process equal to the total processors divided by 4.

Do you think it is possible? My problem is I don't know where to search to do this.
I am currently looking at MPI groups and communicators, am I following the good path to reach my goal?

EDIT : 
The system scheduler is Loadleveler. When I submit a job I need to specify how many nodes I need. There is 16 cores by node et the minimum nodes I can use is 32. In the batch, we specify also -np NBCORES, but if we do so i.e. -np 128, the time consumed will be as if we were using 512 cores (32 nodes) even if the job ran on 128 cores..

Comment: Is 512 the minumum for a given program, or for a parallel environment?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible though with some degree of difficulty.  Before you embark on that journey, what's wrong with a script to start 4 instances of the program ? I'm guessing that there is no requirement for communication between the 4 running instances of your program, so not convinced you need inter- or intra- or any-communicators.

Comment: Sounds like you are running on a Blue Gene/Q system (32 nodes on a node board x 16 cores per node ASIC). If sub-block MPI jobs are allowed, you could use the `--block/--corner/--shape` mechanism of `runjob` to put 4 MPI jobs in 4 corners of a block. Doing so might be site-specific. See [here](http://www.hpc.cineca.it/content/batch-scheduler-loadleveler-0#sub-block) for an example of how it is done on Cineca's FERMI system.

Comment: High Performance Mark : With a script like you say, it will run 4 instances of the program on 512 cores sequentially. Indeed there is no communication between the 4 instances. I can do only one mpirun -np 512.
Hristo Iliev : Thanks for your answer, I will try if I can do what you said.

Thank you a lot for your answers. I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: Francescalus : 512 for a parallel environment, I think. I can specify to run with 128 cores, but they will charge me as if I were calculating with 512 cores.

Comment: Others addressed my question better than I did: ordinarily I would expect to be able to place four 128-core jobs under one 512-core resource allocation.  Could you update the question with system specifics?

Comment: I'm interested in this question too. I can think of two ways of doing it; can someone who knows correct me? If you're using OpenMPI, you could run four processes with `mpirun -np 128 process1 : -np 128 process2 : -np 128 process3 : -np 128 process4`. If your MPI implementation doesn't allow that, you could run each process in the background from your submission script: `mpirun -np 128 process1 &; mpirun -np 128 process2&;` etc. Would either of those work?

Comment: Yossarian : I don't know if it works, but I have come to the conclusion that it is dependent on the scheduler used, but also on how they (the admins) configured it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I were able to do it thanks to your answers.
As I mentioned later (sry for that), the scheduler is Loadlever,
if you have access to the subblock module follow this : http://www.hpc.cineca.it/content/batch-scheduler-loadleveler-0#sub-block as Hristo Iliev mentioned. 
if you don't, you can do a multistep job with no dependency between the steps, so they will be executed simultaneously. It is a classic multistep job, you just have to remove any @dependency flags (in the case of Loadleveler).